# Bootstrap Carousel indicators are not changing on each slide change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Carousel indicators are not changing on each slide change , I have followed same steps from online tuitorial not sure where it is my mistake and followed the answers in SO but no luck.

Please find the code below

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#newSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#newSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div id="newSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://www.stockpilingmoms.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/15-Earth-Day-Tips-and-Ideas.jpg" alt="aa">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>aa</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/ba/fc/0ebafc5f55ba75f0ec7c48c076bb9506.jpg" alt="bb">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>bb</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#newSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#newSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move indicators inside, like below,

```
<div id="newSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#newSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#newSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.stockpilingmoms.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/15-Earth-Day-Tips-and-Ideas.jpg" alt="aa">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>aa</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0e/ba/fc/0ebafc5f55ba75f0ec7c48c076bb9506.jpg" alt="bb">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>bb</h1>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#newSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#newSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```